# C# selenium web driver how do while loop on element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my code in C# I press the delete button and open a pop up where I select the amount of deletions that I want to delete and press again on delete it will delete.
Perhaps it is more correct to ask how I do while this delete element

```
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement (By.LinkText ("Delete")). Click ();
```

As long as it appear true that it will perform the deletion steps and if it does not continue the test

```
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Delete")).Click();
new SelectElement(PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("remove_shares"))).SelectByText("1");
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).Click();
```

---

I want to make a loop if the delete button appear, it will do all the steps of the deletion, and if it does not continue for the other test

---

im try with this code

```
   var links =   PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Delete")).Click();
             while (links = true)
              {
               PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Delete")).Click();
               PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("remove_shares"));
               PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).Click();
             }
```

but i get error
Error   1   Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Answer (score 1):

The first line of code is assigning the return of `.Click()` to the variable `links` but `.Click()` returns `void` (nothing).

The logic for what you want to do is:

1. Check to see if the Delete link exists
2. If it does, click on it
3. Do stuff
4. Repeat 1-3

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Delete")); // gets a collection of elements with Delete as a link
while (links.Any()) // if the collection is not empty, this evaluates to `true`
{
    links.ElementAt(0).Click(); // click the first (and probably only?) element
    // do stuff
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("remove_shares"));
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).Click();
    // get the Delete links again so we can return to the start of the `while` and see if it's still not empty
    links = PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Delete"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help this helped greatly solved my problem,
But I have a question I did not understand this line >  Links.ElementAt (0) .Click (); // click the first (and probably only?) Element
     // do stuff

Comment: It just clicks the first element in the collection. You can take a look at the documentation for `.ElementAt()` for more details.

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!